# How to make a program not utilize 100% cpu?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool

There are 5 threads running in an infinite loop.

2 of them will send messages when queue is not empty.

4 of them will keep sending heartbeat within 5 minutes.

1 of them is to request data from another source.

When it utilizes 100% of the CPU, I can not use any other applications in the window. The whole window becomes very slow.

**EDIT: can sleep be put after WaitOne?**

```
if(autoEvent.WaitOne())
{
}
else
{
}
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

**Can sleep be put after subscriber.Recv() which is ZeroMQ ?**

**all threads i put a sleep if no Recv(), however there is one thread i do not dare to put a sleep in realtime datafeed thread which has only client.Send, will just one thread cause 100% ?**

Comment: Post some code, especially for the _infinite loop_ and _when queue is not empty_

Comment: nice question, but I think the main problem is belong to MS Win Machines, my Win7 is really heavy, it seems it plays with CPU, it took 1G! of the Memory while all of the services have disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: How to make a program not utilize 100% CPU?

A: Don't create a busy loop!!!!

Blocking is Good.  There are lots of ways to accomplish "block until there's something to do".  Including using an alarm signal or timer (poor, but a definite improvement),  doing a socket read with a timeout (if you happen to be notified with a network socket) or using a Windows Event object with a timeout.

Failing all else, you can always use a "Sleep()".  I would discourage using "Sleep" if you can avoid it - there are almost always much better design strategies.  But it *will* keep you from a 100% CPU busy loop ;)

=======================================

Addendum: you posted some code (thank you!)

You're using xxx.WaitOne().

Just use WaitOne() (a blocking call), with a timeout.  This is an IDEAL solution: no busy loop, no "Sleep" required!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332441%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: it is wonderful if put new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) in waitone without missing a signal

Comment: all threads i put a sleep if possible, however there is one thread i do not dare to put a sleep in realtime datafeed thread which has only client.Send, will just one thread cause 100% ?

Comment: Q: Can just one thread cause 100% CPU utilitization?  A: Yes ;)  Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) (100 milliseconds sleep = time for system to do something else) in your infinite loops.

Comment: will it influence subscriber.Recv() when put sleep after it, i just afraid it missing some message

Comment: Can you show some code? It's possible that the Recv() function already is sleeping untill it receives data

Comment: As far as I can see, you do not need Sleep in the thread where you use subscriber.Recv()

Comment: you are right, however there is one thread not have Recv() which is a publisher just sending message

Answer (score 0):

For the threads that send messages, when the queue is emtpy, use a ResetEvent

```
DeliverMessageThread_DoWork
{
  while(true)
  {
    if(GetNextMessage() == null)
      MyAutoResetEvent.WaitOne(); // The thread will suspend here until the ARE is signalled
    else
    {
      DeliverMessage();
      Thread.Sleep(10); // Give something else a chance to do something
     }
  }
}

MessageGenerator_NewMessageArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyAutoResetEvent.Set(); // If the deliver message thread is suspended, it will carry on now until there are no more messages to send
}
```

This way, you won't have 2 threads chewing up all of the CPU cycles all of the time